# Finding largest inscribed square in a plot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm trying to find the largest inscribed square between two lines that intersect at two separate points on a MATLAB plot. First I import two different sets of data as arrays.

Then, after holding the figure, I call the commands

```
plot(dataSet1,dataSet2)
plot(dataSet2,dataSet1)
```

and have both of those plots on the same figure. This gives a graph that looks something like this:

[image: something like this]

My goal is to find the largest square that will fit inside those two lines. Most of what I have seen online is related to black and white matrices, which I believe isn't quite the same as this.

Comment: So you are asking for the algorithm to find such a square? What have you tried? Also it appears that these lines intersect at three points, not two like you are describing.

Comment: @whrrgarbl Sorry I should clarified better. I meant to say that I'm interested in the square inbetween the lines when the lines intersect at two points, not that the lines only intersected twice. I have code for making an increasing bigger square, but I can't seem to get it to recognize when it collides with a line.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand, so in this example it would find two squares? If you post the code, we might be able to help figure out why it's not handling the collisions correctly. (Check out [ask] and [MCVE]; you are more likely to get answers on SO if you include your code in your question.)

Comment: Your description and example slightly diverge: you state that you want the biggest square between two arbitrary lines, while your example shows a special case of `plot(x,y)` followed by its mirror image `plot(y,x)`.